# Alfresco get the node referencies

Tags: alfresco

I don't find any result about a select in the Alfresco Databases. I search in the server application ans anything.
how can I get the node referencies by a select in a database or in a file in terms of the project name ?

Comment: What do you mean by "node reference"? Do you want to get a NodeRef?

Comment: You really need to share more details and be more specific before anyone can even try to help you.

Comment: Yes the node reference for example = e0070d06-7413-4ccd-ab1e-86c28be46a33

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same from going to Admin Tools > Node Browser (login as admin)